# Read XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

In my database, I have a table with XMLs in this format:

```xml
<grdCharges>
  <Row>
    <Code>92015</Code>
    <Description>Manifest Refraction</Description>
    <Units />
    <Mod1 />
    <Mod2 />
    <Mod3 />
    <Mod4 />
    <Ptr1>1</Ptr1>
    <Ptr2 />
    <Ptr3 />
    <Ptr4 />
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Code>92014</Code>
    <Description>Established Patient Comprehensive 180 (108)</Description>
    <Units />
    <Mod1 />
    <Mod2 />
    <Mod3 />
    <Mod4 />
    <Ptr1>1</Ptr1>
    <Ptr2 />
    <Ptr3 />
    <Ptr4 />
  </Row>
</grdCharges>
```

And I want to convert it into the following output:

```
id   Code  Description   
1   92015  Manifest Refraction  
1   92014  Established Patient Comprehensive 180 (108)
```

I have tried doing it this way:

```sql
Create table #XML  
  (    id int  
     , xmldata xml  
  )

insert into #xml values     
 ( 1   
   ,  '<grdCharges>
    <Row>
   <Code>92015</Code>
   <Description>Manifest Refraction</Description>
    <Units />
   <Mod1 />
   <Mod2 />
   <Mod3 />
  <Mod4 />
   <Ptr1>1</Ptr1>
   <Ptr2 />
   <Ptr3 />
   <Ptr4 />
      </Row>
      <Row>
    <Code>92014</Code>
    <Description>Established Patient Comprehensive 180 (108)</Description>
    <Units />
    <Mod1 />
    <Mod2 />
    <Mod3 />
    <Mod4 />
    <Ptr1>1</Ptr1>
    <Ptr2 />
    <Ptr3 />
    <Ptr4 />
    </Row>
    </grdCharges>'

    )

select  id,  
  X.Y.value('.','Varchar(100)') Code  
 ,P.Q.value('.','Varchar(100)') Description  
   from #xml  
         Cross apply xmldata.nodes('/grdCharges/Row/Code') X(Y)  
        Cross apply Y.nodes('/grdCharges/Row/Description') P(Q)
```

But it gives me the following result:

```
id  Code    Description
1   92015   Manifest Refraction
1   92015   Established Patient Comprehensive 180 (108)
1   92014   Manifest Refraction
1   92014   Established Patient Comprehensive 180 (108)
```

I believe that the issue is with the second cross apply. How do I use the second cross apply?

If not a `cross apply` then what else can I do to get the desired result? I need some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own attempt is pretty close...

You use `APPLY` to get a derived table of the *repeating* nodes. This is `<Row>`, while the nodes *within* `<Row>` are the values you want to fetch:

```
select  id,  
  X.Y.value('(Code/text())[1]','Varchar(100)') Code
 ,X.Y.value('(Description/text())[1]','Varchar(100)') Description  
from #xml  
Cross apply xmldata.nodes('/grdCharges/Row') X(Y)
```